Why is the actor loss for actor-critic is multiplied by -1?
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic#3_the_actor-critic_loss
In this TensorFlow guide for the Actor-Critic method, the actor loss is calculated using the following formula:
advantage = returns - values

action_log_probs = tf.math.log(action_probs)

actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_sum(action_log_probs * advantage)

The description says, "A negative term is added to the sum since the idea is to maximize the probabilities of actions yielding higher rewards by minimizing the combined loss."
To my understanding, action_log_probs is always negative.
Then the formula confuses me because multiplying tf.math.reduce_sum(action_log_probs * advantage) by -1 means that when advantage is positive, actor_loss becomes positive. Assuming that tha higher advantege is better, minimizing the actor_loss would adjust the parameters to minimize the probabilities of actions yielding higher rewards.
Is advantage always negative and is a smaller advantage better?
I ran the code and printed out advantage by tf.print('advantage: ', advantage), which showed that advantage is always negative.
Could you explain why advantage is negative and why a smaller advantage is better?
An image of the figure showing the advantage values over the last 500 steps of the final episode
